# Login works on backend but not on frontend

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, frontend

I am working on a Q&A web platform and I just started frontend using Angular and I am trying to route both backend and frontend and test out login from the frontend interface.

The thing is, the login works great on backend using Swagger but if I try to test it using the frontend interface I get a fail error. If I look into the inspect element into the 'Network' tab it looks like my json payload is sent to the requested url but I don't get any response.

This is what the the console error looks like:

```
login.component.ts:29 Login failed 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: _HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://localhost:7152/api/Users/login', ok: false, …}
error   @   login.component.ts:29
Zone - XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:error (async)        
onSubmit    @   login.component.ts:23
LoginComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_1_listener    @   login.component.html:2
Show 108 more frames
login.component.ts:23 
 POST http://localhost:7152/api/Users/login net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
onSubmit    @   login.component.ts:23
LoginComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_1_listener    @   login.component.html:2
Show 89 more frames
```

This is my login component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent {
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      const { username, password } = this.loginForm.value;
      this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          console.log('Login successful', response);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error('Login failed', error);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This is my authentication service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/Users/login`, { username, password });
  }

  register(data: any): Observable<any> {
    // Adjust the URL and body as per your API requirements for registration
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/register`, data);
  }

  // Add other methods here
}
```

LoginDto:

```
public class LoginDto
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The login method in ASP.NET:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginDto loginDto)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginDto.Username);
    if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginDto.Password))
    {
        var token = GenerateJwtToken(user);
        return Ok(new { Token = token, Username = user.UserName });
    }

    return Unauthorized("Invalid login attempt.");
}
```